# Remove all elements if contain a string

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to remove any element if it's innerHTML contains a certain string.

I have this code:

```
 elemItem = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
 elemItemPrice = document.getElementsByClassName("price");
    for (i = 0; i < elemItem.length; i++) {
        if (elemItemPrice[i].innerHTML.trim().indexOf("Sold") != -1){
            elemItem[i].parentNode.removeChild(elemItem[i])
        }
    }
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="item">
<span class="price">Sold</span>
</div>
<div class="item">
<span class="price">Sold</span>
</div>
<div class="item">
<span class="price">$4.99</span>
</div>
```

For me, it's only removing 1 of the sold div tags..

Comment: How is the `Sold` text getting there? Seems like it's probably dynamic, either on the client or server. If so, it would be a little cleaner to add a `sold` class to the element so that you wouldn't have to `.indexOf()` the `.innerHTML`.

Comment: If you want to test the text, then innerHTML is the wrong property to use. Better to use *textContent* or *innerText*. Also, *getElementsByClassName* is not supported by IE 8 and lower.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, when you remove an item, you change the collection's indexing (ie, the item at i=1 moves to 0).  To correct this, iterate backwards:

```
for (i = elemItem.length-1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
```

Comment: Dang ! i've had these kinds of problems before ..not particularly in JS, but never thought of doing things backwards ! :)

Comment: Ah, thank you! It didn't work at first but then I made it elemItem.length - 1.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the filter method of the array, as seen in this SO question: [array.select() in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990175/array-select-in-javascript)