# How to implement sizzle's :gt filter in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to port over a jQuery plugin I have to be compatible with AngularJS JQlite API but have come across a few road blocks. Here's the plugin:

```
    (function (e) {

    var $product = $('#product'),
        $imgs = $product.find('.child'),
        imageTotal = $imgs.length - 1,
        clicked = false,
        widthStep = 4,
        currPos,
        currImg = 0,
        lastImg = 0;
    $imgs.bind('mousedown', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent dragging images
    })
        .filter(':gt(0)').addClass('notseen');

    $product.bind('mousedown touchstart', function (e) {
        if (e.type == "touchstart") {
            currPos = window.event.touches[0].pageX;
        } else {
            currPos = e.pageX;
        }
        clicked = true;

    });
    $(document)
        .bind('mouseup touchend', function () {
        clicked = false;
    })
        .bind('mousemove touchmove', function (e) {
            fadeInOut();
        if (clicked) {
            var pageX;
            if (e.type == "touchmove") {
                pageX = window.event.targetTouches[0].pageX;
            } else {
                pageX = e.pageX;
            }
            widthStep = 4;
            if (Math.abs(currPos - pageX) >= widthStep) {
                if (currPos - pageX >= widthStep) {
                    currImg++;
                    if (currImg > imageTotal) {
                        currImg = 0;
                    }
                } else {
                    currImg--;
                    if (currImg < 0) {
                        currImg = imageTotal;
                    }
                }
                currPos = pageX;
                $imgs.eq(lastImg).addClass('notseen');
                $imgs.eq(currImg).removeClass('notseen');
                lastImg = currImg;
                // $obj.html('<img src="' + aImages[options.currImg] + '" />');
            }
        }
    });


});
```

All it's doing is creating 360 rotating effect, which can be demoed **[here](http://codepen.io/mhartington/pen/vaGrn/)**.

Now the issue is some of these jquery specific APIs. Things like `.filter(':gt(0)')` to select items in an array with an index greater than 0 and pageX. I've done some research on `.filter(':gt(0)')` and [came across a native javascript method of filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990175/array-select-in-javascript) but it seems to only filter a specific index (index of 2, 6, 13, not >0).

Any ideas on how to implement this filter in a pure javascript format? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you don't have to *rewrite* it (and probably don't want to, either), just expose it in a service. and just make sure you're including (the full) jQuery in your app.

Comment: That's what I've been doing and its worked find but I want to try and get rid of JQuery as a dependency (person reasons and file size).

Comment: i wouldn't bother too much with it - if you really don't want jQuery around, just try and find an equivalent plugin as an angular module. anyhow i suggest you edit your question to address the specific issue at hand (i.e. *how to implement sizzle's `:gt` selector in vanilla javascript*), and enclose the method you came across as a reference.

Comment: I'm not familiar with jqLite, is the element array just an ordinary array? is it an object that acts like an array like a jquery object? or what. I suspect you could make use of [].slice to get what you want.

Comment: Angular's JQlite basically provides a handful of methods compared to full size jquery.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using filter, you could use `[].slice` to get all indexes of the array greater than n.

```
$([].slice.call($imgs,1)).addClass("notseen");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rm5PC/

this works in jquery too:

http://jsfiddle.net/rm5PC/1/

Comment: Awesome, tried this out and works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

filter simply loops through the elements list and filter them based on the selector. Since you only need to check gt(0) which is basically all elements except the first on, you can replace the filter with a for loop and skipping the first element. e.g.

```
for (var i=1; i<$imgs.length; i++){
    $($imgs[i]).addClass('notseen');
}
```

Here is an example in http://jsfiddle.net/gdMgp/

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar to that [SO question you mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990175/array-select-in-javascript) but add an additional parameter to the callback. That additional param will be treated as the index NOT the value.

`var filteredArray = array.filter(function(x, y) { return y > 0;})` will give `filteredArray` all the values in `array` greater than index `0`.